# Excel to Server back to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

Is there a way of selecting data from Excel (via the Office Script API, or some Excel JavaScript API), sending that to a server (where any data - e.g. as an Array or JSON payload, can be processed, e.g. validation checks), and then if that passes, sending that data (i) to a database, or back to the Excel file (ii) but in another worksheet. Or if the process fails (data doesn't pass) sending a message / alert back to the user.

Is that possible? Starting with Excel Desktop as the data input source?

I'd like the Javascript (Excel API / Office Script) that sends the data to the server (running Node.js or Django) to be triggered by attaching it to a button in Excel

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks,

ST

Comment: Yes, that can be done using office-js (or VBA for that matter)